# EF core exception System.ArgumentException:Argument types do not match System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Condition(Expression test, Expression ....)

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entityframework-core 2.1.4, want to run following query and trying to get value from navigation property based on some condition.

```cs
var openInvoiceData = _Context.Invoice
    .Where(i => i.InvoiceDate.Date == model.CurrentDate.Date)
    .Select(i => new Contracts.OpenInvoiceData() {
        CustomerId = i.BillToId != null && i.BillTo.CustomerBillTo.Where(x => x.CustomerType == Enum.EnumCustomerType.BillTo).FirstOrDefault() != null
           ? i.BillTo.CustomerBillTo.Where(x => x.CustomerType == Enum.EnumCustomerType.BillTo).FirstOrDefault().Customer.CustomerId 
           : i.Customer.CustomerId
    }).ToList();
```

When its true part executed, its returning following exception.

```
System.ArgumentException: Argument types do not match
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Condition(Expression test, Expression ifTrue, Expression ifFalse, Type type)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ConditionalExpression.Update(Expression test, Expression ifTrue, Expression ifFalse)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.SqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ConditionalExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ThrowingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.SqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.SqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitUnary(UnaryExpression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.UnaryExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Remotion.Linq.Parsing.ThrowingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.SqlTranslatingExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.RelationalProjectionExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberAssignment(MemberAssignment node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberBinding(MemberBinding node)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit[T](ReadOnlyCollection`1 nodes, Func`2 elementVisitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.RelationalProjectionExpressionVisitor.VisitMemberInit(MemberInitExpression memberInitExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.RelationalProjectionExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitSelectClause(SelectClause selectClause, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitSelectClause(SelectClause selectClause, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Remotion.Linq.Clauses.SelectClause.Accept(IQueryModelVisitor visitor, QueryModel queryModel)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryModelVisitorBase.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryModelVisitor.VisitQueryModel(QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](QueryModel queryModel)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](Expression query, IQueryModelGenerator queryModelGenerator, IDatabase database, IDiagnosticsLogger`1 logger, Type contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass13_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Remotion.Linq.QueryableBase`1.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddEnumerable(IEnumerable`1 enumerable)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at TintPro.Repository.InvoiceRepository.GetOpenInvoices(GetOpenInvoice model) in C:\\Devendra Work\\TintPro\\Source BitBucket\\TintProAPI\\Repository\\Repository\\InvoiceRepository.cs:line 163
   at TintPro.Services.InvoiceService.GetOpenInvoices(GetOpenInvoice model) in C:\\Devendra Work\\TintPro\\Source BitBucket\\TintProAPI\\Services\\Service\\InvoiceService.cs:line 486
   at TintProAPI.Controllers.InvoiceController.GetOpenInvoice(GetOpenInvoice model) in C:\\Devendra Work\\TintPro\\Source BitBucket\\TintProAPI\\TintProAPI\\Controllers\\InvoiceController.cs:line 159
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
```

I noticed the following things:

1. The exception is throwing only when I'm trying to get value from Customer navigation property, which is written in its true part, that is

```cs
? i.BillTo.CustomerBillTo.Where(x => x.CustomerType == Enum.EnumCustomerType.BillTo).FirstOrDefault().Customer.CustomerId
```

2. If I use the following statement instead of this, then it's working

```cs
? i.BillTo.CustomerBillTo.Where(x => x.CustomerType == Enum.EnumCustomerType.BillTo).FirstOrDefault().CustomerId
```

I'm unable to catch the cause of this problem, please help.

Comment: Such exceptions indicate EF Core bugs/shortcomings, so one can't really catch the cause. What you can do is to check if it's fixed in a newer EF Core version, or play with alternative query constructs which produce the desired result and find the one (if any) that is working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems Navigational properties are not loading. You will have to use `Include()` Method to load . Try below code to perform this

```
var openInvoiceData = _Context.Invoice
          .Where(i =>
          i.InvoiceDate.Date == model.CurrentDate.Date)
          .Select(i => new Contracts.OpenInvoiceData()
          {
              CustomerId = i.BillToId != null && i.BillTo.CustomerBillTo.Include(d=>d.Customer).Where(x => x.CustomerType == Enum.EnumCustomerType.BillTo).FirstOrDefault() != null
       ? i.BillTo.CustomerBillTo.Include(d=>d.Customer).Where(x => x.CustomerType == Enum.EnumCustomerType.BillTo).FirstOrDefault().Customer.CustomerId 
       : i.Customer.CustomerId
          }).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment, when use above code getting compilation error:  

Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS1061 'ICollection<CustomerBillTo>' does not contain a definition for 'Include' and no accessible extension method 'Include' accepting a first argument of type 'ICollection<CustomerBillTo>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) TintPro.Repository \Repository\Repository\InvoiceRepository.cs 177 Active...



Already added namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue is foreign key is not properly set in the CustomerBillTo entity. Just double check you have done it correctly as bellow.

```
public class CustomerBillTo 
{
    [Required]
    [ForeignKey("Customer")]
    public string CustomerId { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
}
```

Also since your are accessing as `.FirstOrDefault().Customer.CustomerId`. You must have Customer with CustomerBillTo Entity. So make it Required. If not you will have to deal with null reference exception as well.

Comment: Foregin Key relationship is properly setup, and I verify the data also in backend records are available. here is the table structure of customerBillTo table
public partial class CustomerBillTo:DomainEntity
  {
    public Guid CustomerId { get; set; }
    public Guid BillToId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    public virtual BillTo BillTo { get; set; }
    public EnumCustomerType CustomerType { get; set; }
    

  }